# OpenSMTPD: Mails that should be in root user's mbox is in default user's mail box

Tags: email, openbsd, smtp

So I have setup an OpenSMTPD server on my OpenBSD VPS.
I have specified the aliases file path and configured action "local_mail" to forward the mails to specific users based on their corresponding aliases in `/etc/mail/smtpd.conf`. (I am using ... to refer to lines that I haven't specified in the following code blocks.)

```
...
table aliases file:/etc/mail/aliases
...
action "local_mail" mbox alias <aliases>
...
```

The `/etc/mail/aliases` file currently looks like this

```
# Basic system aliases -- these MUST be present
MAILER-DAEMON: postmaster
postmaster: root

# General redirections for important pseudo accounts
daemon: root
ftp-bugs: root
operator: root
www:    root

...

mail: qwerty
```

Where qwerty is my username.

**Issue: All mails sent to postmaster should be found in the root user's mbox. But instead it pops up in qwerty user's mbox.**

Comment: Did you reload `smtpd` after changing the `aliases` file? Also, `/var/log/maillog` might give some hints. You an also run `smtpd` on the foreground and print the trace of the address expansion (`smtpd -d -T expand`) and then send an email to `postmaster` and see what is going on.

Comment: Also: are you aliasing `root` to some other address, e.g. `root: mail` or `root: qwerty`?